# How to compile java project with false @Override in eclipse/java/android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin, annotations, compiler-errors

I have dowloades the [sources of the android musicplayer vanilla](https://github.com/kreed/vanilla). When i compile it with eclipse i get several compiler-error
that complain that a method with @Override is not an override.

I made the source compilable by removing the false @Overrides.

I donot know, why there are these wrong @Overrides.

Maybe they are there because the autor developed for an other android-baseclasslibrary that has these methods while my
 java 6 with android 2.1 does not have it.

Is there a way to make it compileable without deleting the false @Overrides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to JDK6 :

- Enable Java 1.6 Compiler in your project properties under Java Compiler
- Make sure your java Runtime Environement is at 1.6

Comment: i have a java 1.6 compiler but i was compiling with java 1.5 settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from using different versions.

It's not a good practice to ***make it compileable without deleting the false @Overrides*** because it is made for a reason and if you **CAN** disable it, you may have problems elsewhere and you wouldn't know where the problems are happening

So, just delete the false or check for a newer version of vanilla